# Вопрос по сортировке в php

Tags: php

Имеется код, который отображает список файлов XML в каталоге

```
     $dir = "xml";

        if (is_dir($dir)) {
            if ($dh = opendir($dir)) { 
                while ($file = readdir($dh)) {
                    if (!is_dir($file)) {
                        if( strtoupper(substr($file, -4))=='.XML' ) {                       
                            echo "<table><tr><td><a href='x.php?f=$file' title= 'Просмотр' >$file</a></td></tr></table><br />";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Как сделать чтобы файлы отображались по дате добавления, а не в алфавитном порядке?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Заносите в массив и сортируйте с помощью функции uasort.
Если у вас новая версия php, то вместо `cmp` может быть лямбда-функция.

```
$files = array();

if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while ($file = readdir($dh)) {
            if (!is_dir($file)) {
                if( strtoupper(substr($file, -4))=='.XML' ) {
                    $files[] = array(
                        'name' => $file,
                        'date' => filectime($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file)
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ( $a['date'] == $b['date']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return $a['date'] < $b['date']?  -1 : 1;
}
uasort($files, 'cmp');

foreach ( $files as $file ) {
    echo "<table><tr><td><a href='x.php?f=$file[name]' title= 'Просмотр' >$file[name]</a></td></tr></table><br />";
}
```

Comment: Дружище, спасибо, работает! Очень помог!

Comment: Как тебе + поставить?))

Answer (score 0):

Самый разумный вариант при пролистывании сквозь директорию заносить файлы в ассоциативный архив `$files[$file] = filemtime($file);`, а после отсортировать архив `asort($files);`

Т.е. в Вашем варианте:

```
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) { 
        $files = Array();
        while ($file = readdir($dh)) {
            if (!is_dir($file)) {
                if( strtoupper(substr($file, -4))=='.XML' ) {
                    $files[$file] = filemtime($file);
                 }
             }
         }

         asort($files);

         foreach(array_values(($files) as $file) {
              echo "<table><tr><td><a href='x.php?f=$file' title= 'Просмотр' >$file</a></td></tr></table><br />";
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Представьте, что будет, если у двух файлов будет одинаковая дата изменения (создания).

Comment: возможно... Тогда делаем иначе. Записываем имена файлов в ключи архива и сортируем по значениям... Исправлено....